# Add serialised data to wp database from form of radio buttons via AJAX

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, wordpress, serialization

I have a wordpress post which displays a form consisting of several listed songs, each song has 2 radio buttons ("Play" and "Don't Play").

I want to store the data of these radio buttons in my database as 2 sets of serialised data, i.e if the "Play" radio button is checked

1:do_play = Song name 1
2:do_play = Song name 2
3:do_play = Song name 3
4:do_play = Song name 4
5:do_play = Song name 5

```
a:5:{i:0;s:11:"Song name 1";i:1;s:11:"Song name 2";i:2;s:11:"Song name 3";i:3;s:11:"Song name 4";i:4;s:11:"Song name 5";}
```

And for songs selected from "Don't Play", the same, but in a different DB row:

1:do_play = Song name 6
2:do_play = Song name 7
3:do_play = Song name 8
4:do_play = Song name 9
5:do_play = Song name 10

```
a:5:{i:0;s:11:"Song name 6";i:1;s:11:"Song name 7";i:2;s:11:"Song name 8";i:3;s:11:"Song name 9";i:4;s:11:"Song name 10";}
```

I want to do this via AJAX, and add the entries to the wp_postmeta table. Here is an example of my form html:

```
<form id="songChoices-12028" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="booking_id" name="booking_id" value="12028">
        <ul class="setlist_container">


            <li class="song_entry ">Ain’t No Sunshine - 
                <em>Bill Withers</em>
                <br>

                    <input type="radio" id="doPlay" name="songChoice-397">
                    <label for="doPlay">Do</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="dontPlay" name="songChoice-397">
                    <label for="dontPlay">Don't</label>
                    <a href="#" id="clear-button">Clear</a>
            </li>

            <li class="song_entry ">No Diggity - 
                <em>Blackstreet</em>
                <br>

                    <input type="radio" id="doPlay" name="songChoice-12036">
                    <label for="doPlay">Do</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="dontPlay" name="songChoice-12036">
                    <label for="dontPlay">Don't</label>
                    <a href="#" id="clear-button">Clear</a>
            </li>

            <li class="song_entry 7-8-piece drinks-reception">Pricetag - 
                <em>Jessie J</em>
                <br>

                    <input type="radio" id="doPlay" name="songChoice-12038">
                    <label for="doPlay">Do</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="dontPlay" name="songChoice-12038">
                    <label for="dontPlay">Don't</label>
                    <a href="#" id="clear-button">Clear</a>
            </li>

            <li class="song_entry 4-5-piece">Rehab - 
                <em>Amy Winehouse</em>
                <br>

                    <input type="radio" id="doPlay" name="songChoice-12039">
                    <label for="doPlay">Do</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="dontPlay" name="songChoice-12039">
                    <label for="dontPlay">Don't</label>
                    <a href="#" id="clear-button">Clear</a>
            </li>

            <li class="song_entry 4-5-piece">Rolling in the Deep - 
                <em>Adele</em>
                <br>

                    <input type="radio" id="doPlay" name="songChoice-12035">
                    <label for="doPlay">Do</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="dontPlay" name="songChoice-12035">
                    <label for="dontPlay">Don't</label>
                    <a href="#" id="clear-button">Clear</a>
            </li>

            <li class="song_entry 4-5-piece">Sittin’ on the Dock of the Bay - 
                <em>Otis Redding</em>
                <br>

                    <input type="radio" id="doPlay" name="songChoice-398">
                    <label for="doPlay">Do</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="dontPlay" name="songChoice-398">
                    <label for="dontPlay">Don't</label>
                    <a href="#" id="clear-button">Clear</a>
            </li>

            <li class="song_entry 4-5-piece">Summer of ’69 - 
                <em>Bryan Adams</em>
                <br>

                    <input type="radio" id="doPlay" name="songChoice-12037">
                    <label for="doPlay">Do</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="dontPlay" name="songChoice-12037">
                    <label for="dontPlay">Don't</label>
                    <a href="#" id="clear-button">Clear</a>
            </li>
                        </ul>
    </form>
```

Then in my ajax JS file I have:

```
var response;

// AJAX for song request details
$('form[id^="songChoice-"]').on('change', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

$.post( update_user_info.ajaxurl, {
      action : 'update_user_setlist',
      nonce : update_user_info.nonce,
      post : $(this).serialize()
  },
  function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      responseSuccess(response);
  });

return false;

});
```

Then, most importantly, the function that handles sending the data to the DB:

```
function updateSetlistInfo() {

    if(empty($_POST) || !isset($_POST)) {
        self::ajaxStatus('error', 'Nothing to update.');
    } else {
        $data = $_POST;

        $dataString = $data['post'];
        parse_str($dataString, $dataArray);

        $nonce = $data['nonce'];

        if(wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'update_user_info') !== false) {

            $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
            $post_id = $dataArray['booking_id'];
            //$dataArray['user_addressLine1'] = isset($dataArray['user_addressLine1']) ? $dataArray['user_addressLine1'] : false;


            if($user_ID != NULL) {
                foreach($dataArray as $key=>$value) {

                $status = update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);

            }
                self::ajaxStatus('success', 'Meta fields updated.', $dataArray);

            } else {
                self::ajaxStatus('error', 'You are unauthorized to perform this action.', $dataArray);
            }
        } else {
            self::ajaxStatus('error', 'Nonce check cannot fail.');
        }
    }
}
```

The above is taken from the other form on my page which submits user address details via ajax to the database. However, this just adds a new row per form item - I want to have 2 rows, "do_play" and "dont_play" and build up an array of serialised data within these. any suggestions would be a great help at this point as I'm a little stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you didn't include the complete class that holds the `updateSetlistInfo()` method. But what you provided looks ok.

The first thing i would debug is the `$dataArray`.
Does it indeed hold the 2 (do_play / dont_play) keys?

Add this (just before the foreach call):

```
error_log('$dataArray: <pre>'.print_r($dataArray,true).'</pre>');
```

Can you check?

---

Update 1:
After debugging, we know the dataArray looks like this:

```
array(
  "status" => "success",
  "message" => "Meta fields updated.",
  "data" => array(
    "booking_id" => "12031"
    "songChoice" => array(
      "2" => "dont_play",
      "7" => "dont_play",
    )
  )
)
```

Your foreach saves every (top level) key as a post_meta_key.

Like this:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'status', 'success');
update_post_meta($post_id, 'message', 'Meta fields updated.');
update_post_meta($post_id, 'data', ARRAY_THAT_HOLDS_BOOKINGID_SONGCHOICE);
```

I hope you understand what's going on now. As a developer you have to use the debug log ALOT. It's always the first thing you go to when you want to check if everything is running as expected.

I'm hoping i've pointed you in the right direction, and you can debug your app further without my help. Because now it's going a bit beyond the scope off stackoverflow, i can't help you debug your app step by step.

---

**WP Debugging**
In your `wp-config.php`, change:

```
define( "WP_DEBUG", false );
```

Into:

```
define( "WP_DEBUG", true );// just toggle this line to false to turn off
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    define( "WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY", false );
    define( "WP_DEBUG_LOG", true );
    @ini_set( "display_errors", 0 );
    define( "SCRIPT_DEBUG", true );
}
```

Then install a [debug log viewer](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-log-viewer/) plugin.

Comment: Hi @Bjorn - could you explain the best way to debug what is in $dataArray?

Comment: Ok perfect, i've installed debug log viewer, changed wp-config.php and added tht line before the foreach statement in my updateSetlistinfo() function - currently no errors showing in debug viewer when I submit

Comment: add `error_log('debug log working');` directly in your functions.php and confirm that it's working.

Comment: ok, so you tried the ajax call but you don't see the `$dataArray` log entry. This means the code isn't called. Now you can go up the chain and try debugging untill you see the log, you'll then know where the code execution stops. I would start with placing an `error_log()` right after the `updateSetlistInfo()` opening tag to check if it's actually called by ajax action hook.

Comment: One more thing, did you just copy this code from somewhere, do you have any wp_ajax knowledge? I'm trying to understand your skill level. I'm assuming you use the wright action hooks to setup the ajax call. Where do you call the ajax, front or back-end?

Comment: Hi there, ok I have it all plumbed in now and get the following in my debug: `$dataArray: <pre>Array `
also in console I get: `{"status":"success","message":"Meta fields updated.","data":{"booking_id":"12031","songChoice":{"2":"dont_play","7":"dont_play"}}}` on submit
Skill level is reasonably basic when it comes to wp_ajax - finding my feet a little